# Does Postgres only allow one index with the same name?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

In MySQL I can have the same index (same name and columns) in different tables.
From what I am seeing so far, Postgres only allows me to have one index with a name, even if I try to create it in a different table.

Does Postgres really not allow indexes with the same name or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, and indexes, tables, views and sequences share the same name space, so any two of these objects cannot have the same name if they are in the same schema (= name space).

You can see that from the table definition of the catalog table `pg_class`, which contains all these objects:

```
\d pg_class

                     Table "pg_catalog.pg_class"
       Column        │     Type     │ Collation │ Nullable │ Default 
═════════════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═════════
 oid                 │ oid          │           │ not null │ 
 relname             │ name         │           │ not null │
[...]
Indexes:
    "pg_class_oid_index" UNIQUE, btree (oid)
    "pg_class_relname_nsp_index" UNIQUE, btree (relname, relnamespace)
    "pg_class_tblspc_relfilenode_index" btree (reltablespace, relfilenode)
```

The second index `pg_class_relname_nsp_index` forces the combination of name and schema to be unique.